# Can I swap CTRL and COMMAND on the Mac keyboard for a single app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, remapping

I already know I can swap CTRL and COMMAND on a Mac via the keyboard preferences.  But I want to do this for a specific app, not system-wide.  (More accurately I *have* swapped them system-wide but I want to un-swap them for a specific app.)

I've seen other SU posts about similar things, but not for a specific app.  Anyone know how to do this?  I don't mind installing a driver or what have you to do this.  I just really need this functionality.

Also, to be clear, this is for remapping the ***keys***, not ***key combinations or shortcuts*** so the duplicate this was flagged as is incorrect.  This is more digging into intercepting key codes directly at the OS level if that makes sense.

Comment: Consider mentioning the specific program you want this for. Or, having a hunch what this is about, explain the problem, not what you think might be a solution.

Comment: Not sure how to be more specific.  I want the system to swap the keys when a specific app gets the focus.  Which app is irrelevant as I'm asking about modifying what the keyboard even sends to the app, which is why I mentioned a driver.  If I were to replace the default keyboard driver I could define any criteria to do any number of things with the key mappings, which is why I suggested that.

Comment: Voting to close as the user indicated in the other topic's comments that a general solution applicable for the other topic is what he needs.

Comment: Actually they are not the same.  That post is for key combinations, similar to what yo can do in system preferences but for a specific app.  I am asking about remapping actual keys themselves, similar to what you would do at the driver level  This is a different thing entirely.

Comment: @techie, as I clearly stated above, I am looking to do this for a specific app only.  It is not a duplicate of the one you linked to.  It's close, but that one is for system-wide changes.  I'm looking to override the keys for a specific application.  If the apps the other post specified can be set to only work for a specific app, that would be sufficient, but until then, this is different.